# Showing two buttons on a table row built from state object in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, hover, components, row

I've built a table which has content in table rows based on state objects in the root component file of my application. The states are passed as props to a component file where they are rendered and outputted as a table row. How would I go about showing 2 buttons edit and delete that show up in only the row in which the user hovers over using React? I have assigned an id value for each state object.

Here is what I would like for it to look like:
[2 buttons show when hovering over table row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/COQVB.png)

Here is what my component return function looks like

```
<tbody class="tbody" key="shoe.id">
                <tr class="tr">
                    <td class="td">
                        {shoe.name}
                        <td>
                            <Button className="edit-delete-buttons" variant="tertiary" size="xs">Edit</Button>
                            <Button className="edit-delete-buttons" variant="tertiary" size="xs">Delete</Button>
                        </td>
                    </td>
                    <td class="td">
                        <div>{shoe.maker}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.company}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.wearer ? shoe.wearer : null}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.type ? shoe.type : null}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.style ? shoe.style : null}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.color ? shoe.color : null}</div>

                        <div>{shoe.description ? shoe.description : null}  </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td class="td">
                        {shoe.quantity}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

edit:

```
const TableRender = (props) => {
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
const shoesList = props.shoes.map(shoe => {
        return(
                <tbody class="tbody" key="shoe.id">
                <tr class="tr" onMouseOver={() => setShow(!show)} onMouseOut={() => setShow(!show)} key={shoe.id}>
                    <td class="td">
                        {shoe.name}
                       {show && (
                        <td>
                            <Button className="edit-delete-buttons" variant="tertiary" size="xs">Edit</Button>
                            <Button className="edit-delete-buttons" variant="tertiary" size="xs">Delete</Button>
                        </td>
                        )}
                    </td>
                    <td class="td">
                        <div>{shoe.maker}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.company}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.wearer ? shoe.wearer : null}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.type ? shoe.type : null}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.style ? shoe.style : null}</div>
                        <div>{shoe.color ? shoe.color : null}</div>

                        <div>{shoe.description ? shoe.description : null}  </div>  
                    </td>
                    <td class="td">
                        {shoe.quantity}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        )
    })
    return(
        //output shoeeventsList
        <Fragment>
            {shoeeventsList}
        </Fragment>
    )
}
 }
 export default TableRender;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set state for button's display and use `onMouseOver` and `onMouseOut` on `<tr />` to update state

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
const dataRow = ["row1", "row2"];
export default function App() {
  const [indexRow, setIndex] = useState(null);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <tbody class="tbody" key="shoe.id">
        {dataRow.map((item, index) => (
          <tr
            class="tr"
            onMouseOver={() => setIndex(index)}
            onMouseOut={() => setIndex(null)}
          >
            <td class="td">
              Shoe name
              {indexRow === index && (
                <td>
                  <button
                    className="edit-delete-buttons"
                    variant="tertiary"
                    size="xs"
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                  <button
                    className="edit-delete-buttons"
                    variant="tertiary"
                    size="xs"
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </td>
              )}
            </td>
            <td class="td">
              <div>shoe maker</div>
              <div>shoe company</div>
            </td>
            <td class="td">shoe.quantity</td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can check [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-gould-nmvy5)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to implement it as a component so I have class TableRender. When I implement what you suggested I get a Hook error. What do I need to change in my original class for it to not have that error? Sorry I'm new to React. Please see my code in the edit

Comment: Okay I got it working so that the two buttons show when hovered on. But I just want the specific row that the user hovers on to show the two buttons. Right now if i hover over any row the 2 buttons appear on all rows of the table. How would I go about doing this? Thanks for the help again

Comment: you need to set index of row as state and if that state equal `<tr />` index, you can show button. I have updated answer and codeSandBox, please check

Comment: Is there anyway to set the index of the row to to the id value of the state which has the content that appears in each row?

Comment: i updated [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-gould-nmvy5) is it correct for you?

Comment: Yea its correct for what i posted but was really looking for  something that could work with varying state quantities. But ill give you the best answer